# OOP : Java Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

If I have an array of ints

```
int[] array1 = new int[10];
```

I create second array like this

```
int[] array2 = array1;
```

And now If I make changes in array2 will it affect on array 1? Are they the same in computer memory? or they are refering to different memory blocks?

Answer (score 3):

> I create second array like this

```
int[] array2 = array1;
```

This does not create an array. It creates a new reference called `array2` to the same array as `array1` refers to.

> And now If I make changes in array2 will it affect on array 1? Are they the same in computer memory? or they are refering to different memory blocks?

Yes, Yes and No

Answer (score 2):

`array1` and `array2` are 2 *different references* to the same array instance (memory location)